# Unsupported certificate option "-t" at cpanel terminal

Tags: ssh, terminal, git, cpanel

I'm creating a ssh key authentication in the cpanel terminal as recommended by cpanel, So I'll be able to integrate git version control:

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4404218477207-How-to-Configure-SSH-Key-Authentication-for-Use-with-cPanel-Git-Version-Control

Running 2nd step from the guide, I'm getting the error:

> "Unsupported certificate option "-t""

[image: cpanel error image]

2nd step command from the cPanel guide (which I discover it's missing the option "-O" whose is necessary for the authentication type ed25519)

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "youremailaddress@domain.tld DAY-MONTH-YEAR" -f ~/.ssh/my_key
```

Comment: Compare all the options in the guide with all the options you're actually running

Comment: @user1686 I didn't understand your comment. I'm using exactly the same options from the guide, I just changed the comment. I've even tried running the same command from the guide without change anything and didn't work, doing so I receive another error: `unknown key type ed25519`.

Comment: Your screenshot shows otherwise. What's the `-O` option doing there?

Comment: the option "-O" is necessary for the authentication type ed25519, otherwise I will have `unknown key type ed25519`.

Comment: That's not how it works at all... if your OpenSSH version doesn't support ed25519, then you would still have `unknown key type ed25519` _anyway,_ regardless of what you add – options can't enable support for algorithms that literally aren't in the program. The only reason you're not getting the same error right now is because it fails _before_ checking the type.

Comment: I understand, thank you, how can I make my ssh access support this key?